# Regex captures the last word of match as a group

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have a simple a regex like so `_(([a-zA-Z]|_)*)` to match the words anything after underscore like so `_price_range * _qty_val`, the catpure words which I am looking for `price_range, qty_val` but for weird mistake there are three matching groups, the last one being the last words of the matching word which is `e` and `l` in my case. Can someone explain or let me what I am doing wrong here? I don't want the last matching group.

Please check the screenshot. [image]

Comment: Did you mean to match any 0+ letters or underscores after `_`? Then use a single capturing group, `_([a-zA-Z_]+)`

Comment: That works, can you point out my mistake?

Comment: Nested capturing groups was  the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unexpected capture group is group 2, which is the inner brackets `([a-zA-Z]|_)`.

A simple fix would be to make that group non-capturing:

```
_((?:[a-zA-Z]|_)*)
```

`[a-zA-Z]|_` can be simplified to `[a-zA-Z_]`, so your regex can just be this:

```
_([a-zA-Z_]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([example here](https://regex101.com/r/f6qeeV/2))

```
_[^ *]*     or grouped     _([^ *]*)
```

```js
let s = "_price_range * _qty_val"

let r = s.match(/_[^ *]*/g).slice(0).map(x=>x.substr(1));

console.log(r);
```